# Can I store a raw KML file into a SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, kml

I'm a developer of an public transportation android app and I have a KML file for each bus line. Can I simply store a hole KML file on a SQLite database as a TEXT? There's a better way of doing this?

Each KML has the 2 routes for one bus line. There is around 380 bus lines.

Comment: Is a KML file a text file?

Comment: Yes. It's like a XML file to store Geo data, used by google maps and others.

Comment: As a TEXT is possible i would think. Or as blob.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could store KML "TEXT" ... but sqlite normally stores GIS data using it's own openGIS geometry types with associated coordinate system tables, all defined with an sqlite "GIS enabled Spatialite" database.

A GIS analyst might want to import KML into such an sqlite database (called Spatialite) because of it's excellent geometry types, coordinate systems and SQL functionality, for GIS upkeep, then store the KML data in text fields in another table (for an app designed to work with KML)  And then, if the branches ever need updates within the GIS, a new KML layer can get exported, then the KML text imported again back into the sqlite database, as a brand new joinable table (every time the geometries get any update).  You should be familiar with the QGIS application or Spatialite tools to do that.

SHOULD THIS BE MOVED TO:
GEOGRAPHIC INFORMATION SYSTEMS